# How to capture all the options user selected in a webpage and pass it to the backend using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, django

*I have a requirement to capture all the options which the user has selected and pass them to the backend(view in Django.*

*There are text boxes and Radio buttons on the web page user has to select the options, and on click of a save button based on user selections, I have to initiate the process in the backend.*

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you made any attempt?

Comment: I am new to javascript and thinking to capture every option and put it in a variable and write an AJAX call. But not sure whether that is the right way , Please give me some insights.Thanks